# Android canvas and Bitmap unit

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-drawable

what canvas.drawBitmap unit(DIP, PX, ...???) want for x and y parameter
and also what unit will return when call Bitmap.getWidth() is it in DIP OR PIX OR ....???

i want to create backgammonboard game, when i create board, i am re size original image, and i check original image and re sized image and check percentage, and draw dices, but my problem still it is not work properly in all device, just work fine in my device that programmed in...

i think i confused DIP and PX and Bitmap.getWidth() has diffrent unit that canvas.drawBitmap wants...

**UPDATE**
i put backgammonboard image in drawable-mdpi it has 858Px but when i use ((BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgammonboard)).getBitmap().getWidt‌​h() it will rerutn 1287Px why??

Comment: It's all in px. To scale on different screens resolution you must multiply ny the density scaling factor (0.75 for ldpi screens, 1.0 for mdpi screens, 1.5 for hdpi screens, 2.0 for xhdpi screens, ...)

Comment: i put backgammonboard image in drawable-mdpi it has 858Px but when i use ((BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.backgammonboard)).getBitmap().getWidth() it will rerutn 1287Px why??

Comment: Because your unscaled bitmap is bigger than the screen? By the way, the standard WVGA resolution is 854px, not 858px (or 800 px, the non extended version).

Comment: Excuse me, i cant undrestand, you mean if my unscaled bitmap width is equal to 800px, in all screen resolutions when i call getWidth() allways return 800px? my screen resolution is FULL HD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas, Bitmaps and such are in Pixels.